# Paypal Client Side Rest

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal client side rest and having problem getting the transaction id. Thanks in advance those have an idea how to resolve this problem.

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

  var currency  = payment.transactions[0].amount["currency"];
                var amount      = payment.transactions[0].amount["total"];
                var payerID     = payment.payer.payer_info["payer_id"];
                var pstatus     = payment.payer.status;
   });
        },
```

I tried this two sample below either of the two working fine but the problem is do not match on buyer transaction id.

```
var txn_id      = payment.cart;
var txn_id          = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale["id"];
```